# How to use datediff equivalent in Oracle with YYYYMMDD formatted number?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Oracle database columns with the `number` format `YYYYMMDD`. I have not been successful in using this format with `datediff` to get the difference between two dates. The [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp) I've read online uses a different format:

```
DATEDIFF(day,'2008-06-05','2008-08-05')
```

What's the best way for me to get number of days between two dates given the format available to me in Oracle? Answers not involving `datediff` are acceptable as long as it gets the number of days between two dates with the format `YYYYMMDD`.

Comment: If you are using MySQL, why are you using the syntax for `datediff()` for SQL Server?

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for calling that out. I have been going by the w3schools docs and hadn't noticed this one was exclusive to SQL Server. Any ideas on how to get the datediff for PL/SQL? I'm editing my question to reflect these revelations now.

Comment: So you have an Oracle database.  That database has a table with two different `varchar2` columns that contain a string that represents a date?  Why would you store dates in a `varchar2` column rather than storing dates in a `date` column?

Comment: @JustinCave, the date data is actually stored as `number`. I was not the one who came up with the table, so I wonder the same thing as you.

Comment: If you're using Oracle 11g or greater, you can add a virtual column to the table that gives a `DATE` value based on the value in the `NUMBER` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple subtraction in Oracle:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('20080805','YYYYMMDD') - TO_DATE('20080605','YYYYMMDD')
  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. What if my date data is stored as `number`? Also, what is the purpose of `FROM DUAL`?

Comment: `dual` is a dummy table in Oracle.  Any time you want to select a value from a non-existent table, you can use it.  I.e., `select sysdate from dual;` returns the current date.  I don't understand the other question about it being a number.  You can still parse it the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't have a `DATEDIFF()` function. Instead, you can use simple arithmetic with Oracle dates, where subtracting one date from another gives the number of days, and where you can add an subtract days from a given date. (You can also subtract *fractions* of days, but that might be outside the scope of this answer.)

To convert your `NUMBER` dates of the format `YYYYMMDD` to actual dates, just use the `TO_DATE()` function (I am pretty sure that Oracle will implicitly convert the `NUMBER` value to a `VARCHAR2` before converting to a date; if not, use `TO_CHAR()` to do that explicitly).

```
TO_DATE(20150301, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

To get the difference between two dates, you can do the following:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(my_number_date1, 'YYYYMMDD') - TO_DATE(my_number_date2, 'YYYYMMDD')
  FROM my_table;
```

Incidentally, if you want to get intervals instead of days, convert to timestamp (using `TO_TIMESTAMP()`) instead of converting to date.